# Set programmatically jsonValidation for dynamic mapping

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am creating a new vscode extension, and I need to extend the standard usage of the jsonValidation system already present in vscode.

**Note :** I am talking about the system defined in package.json :

```json
"contributes" : {
    "languages": [
        {
            "id" : "yml", 
            "filenamePatterns": ["module.service"]
        },
        {
            "id" : "json", 
            "filenamePatterns": ["module.*"]
        }
    ],
    "jsonValidation": [
        {
            "fileMatch": "module.test",
            "url": "./resources/test.schema"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I need to create a dynamic mapping, where the json fields filematch/url are defined from some internal rules (like version and other internal stuff). The standard usage is static : one fileMatch -> one schema.

I want for example to read the version from the json file to validate, and set the schema after that :

```json
{
    "version" : "1.1"
}
```

validation schema must be test-schema.1.1 instead of test-schema.1.0

note : The question is only about the modification of the configuration provided by package.json from the extensions.ts

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** EDIT since the previous solution was not working in all cases

There is one solution to modify the package.json at the activating of the function.

```js
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const myPlugin = vscode.extensions.getExtension("your.plugin.id");
    if (!myPlugin)
    {
        throw new Error("Composer plugin is not found...")
    }

    // Get the current workspace path to found the schema later.
    const folderPath = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders;
    if (!folderPath)
    {
        return;
    }
    const baseUri : vscode.Uri = folderPath[0].uri;

    let packageJSON = myPlugin.packageJSON;
    if (packageJSON && packageJSON.contributes && packageJSON.contributes.jsonValidation)
    {
        let jsonValidation = packageJSON.contributes.jsonValidation;
        const schemaUri : vscode.Uri =  vscode.Uri.joinPath(baseUri, "/schema/value-0.3.0.json-schema");            
        const schema = new JsonSchemaMatch("value.ospp", schemaUri)
        jsonValidation.push(schema);
    }
}
```

And the json schema class

```js
class JsonSchemaMatch 
{
    fileMatch: string;
    url : string;

    constructor(fileMatch : string, url: vscode.Uri) 
    {
        this.fileMatch = fileMatch;
        this.url = url.path;
    }
}
```

Another important information is the loading of the element of contributes is not reread after modification, for example

```js
class Language 
{
    id: string;
    filenamePatterns : string[];

    constructor(id : string, filenamePatterns: string[]) 
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.filenamePatterns = filenamePatterns;
    }
}
```

```js
if (packageJSON && packageJSON.contributes && packageJSON.contributes.languages)
    {
        let languages : Language[] = packageJSON.contributes.languages;
        for (let language of languages) {
            if (language.id == "json") {
                language.filenamePatterns.push("test.my-json-type")
            }
        }
    }
```

This change has no effect, since the loading of file association is already done (I have not dig for the reason, but I think this is the case)

In this case, creating a settings.json in the workspace directory can do the job:

settings.json

```json
{
  "files.associations": {
    "target.snmp": "json",
    "stack.cfg": "json"
  }
}
```

Be aware that the settings.json can be created by the user with legitimate reason, so don't override it, just fill it.

Comment: How do you prevent the `vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.reloadWindow');` from creating an infinite loop? For me, after each reloadWindow the package.json is reset and the changes don't stick.

Comment: In my use case I can use a condition on the reload, because I know if the configuration must be reloaded. Maybe you can do the same (In my case, I got a settings file in the user workspace)

Comment: My use case is that I need to add extensions to a language in `contributes.languages` which must come from the package.json, which I believe must be processed when the extension is packaged and then not read again, because I can look at the package.json and see the correct changes, but it isn't used. If you have any ideas for how to make this work I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I was on holiday for my first comment and not access to my coding station. I have done some check and I think your problem is that you are changing some settings read by vscode at the startup of the plugin. I have reached this problem for the language association and in this case, I have created method to update the settings.json. I think that if you cannot change the settings.json to reflect your need you are doomed but I am far to be an expert on vscode.

Comment: I have done the same job, there is one workaround. Add your information inside the file settings.json (in the opened workspace). This setting is read when the workspace is open, be aware not to override the settings.json but add your information as this file can be legitimately used by the user. If you need code example open a question and I will give a answer with an example

Comment: yes I would appreciate an example! Are you saying I can also add extensions to a language in `contributes.languages` from the settings.json as well as the package.json?

Comment: I can show you one solution, just open your own question, that can serve other peoples too. But yes you can